# What to do after login but before essential user data gets returned in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app that uses firebase for authentication.

```
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
```

so basically as soon as user authenticates, this will take to the home screen. but i dont want that, i want to wait on another piece of data from my api, say `onboarded`, if `onboarded == true` then `HomeScreen` otherwise `OnboardingScreen`.

So the tricky part is before that data comes in, i want to stay on the login screen. how do i have the user stay on the LoginScreen? it seems the best way is to have another stream listen to the `onboardedLoading` and combine these 2 streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dart file auth.dart, in that, paste this line of code,

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignInEmail(String email, String password) async {

    AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    assert(user != null);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    print('signInEmail succeeded: $user');

    return user;

  }

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignUp(email, password) async {

    AuthResult result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    assert (user != null);
    assert (await user.getIdToken() != null);

    return user;

  }
```

In your login/ Sigup page, create an instance of my auth class:

```
var authHandler = new Auth();
```

In the onPressed () of your button

```
onPressed: () {
if(onboardedLoading==true){
    authHandler.handleSignInEmail(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
    .then((FirebaseUser user) {
         Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  HomeScreen()));
   }).catchError((e) => print(e));


} 
}else{
//Show An Animation, such as CirclularProgressIndicator.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design a simple loading screen, then use Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil() to whichever screen you need after getting AuthState.